# Why isn't my click event not working in Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, testing, web, junit

When clickevent is fired, I want it to redirect/open new page in same tab. The new tab would be  '/Waiting', however even after click event is fired, it stays in the same page. While doing manually by going to browser's localhost, it works though. Also, even after 10 secs, it doesn't load.

```
@Test
public void firstPlayerConnection() {
    try {
        driver.get(uiPath);
        WebElement startGame = driver.findElement(By.id("startGame"));
        startGame.click();
        WebElement gif = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
                .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("loading")));
        assertEquals("/Waiting", driver.getCurrentUrl());

    } finally {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are there any Null-Pointer Exceptions coming up at `startGame.click()`?

Comment: Any Selenium Exceptions thrown like NoSuchElement, ElementNotVisible etc.?

Comment: Yes. Since the page doesnt load, it says nosuchelement

Comment: When there is an exception in the code where your question is about always provide the stacktrace of the exception and make clear on what line of your code this exception occurs. That makes it much easier to quickly answer your question.

Comment: The noSuchElement exception is not because the page doesn't load but because the startGame button is not clickable at the moment you're clicking on it.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken the NoSuchElement exception must be on the startGame.Click() command. To avoid this exception you have to (explicit) wait till this element is clickable.

```
WebElement startGame = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
            .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("startGame")));
```

Comment: This helped. It was because of absence of implicit/explicit wait

Comment: In your case it has to be explicit because you already have an explicit wait in your code and it's not a good idea to mix implicit and explicit wait because it will give unpredictable wait times. See: https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp.

Answer (score 0):

Provide wait explicitly, & if it still does not work then try to use submit() in place of click().